# How to remove duplicate values in dataframe while preserving the rest of the row in Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, duplicates, jupyter-notebook

I am working on some gross profit reports in a jupyter notebook.  I have exported the data out of our CRM as a csv and am using Pandas to with with the data.  Some of the data is being duplicated in a couple of columns.  I need to remove those duplicate values in those columns, but preserve the rest of the row.

I have tried to drop_duplicates on a subset of the two columns, but it removes the entire row.

```
          INV           INV SUB                 PO Number PO Subtotal  \
0      INV-002504       USD 350.00              PO-03977         240   
1      INV-002507     USD 1,400.00              PO-03846      603.56   
2             NaN              NaN              PO-03847         295   
3      INV-002489       USD 891.25              PO-03861      658.31   
4      INV-002453     USD 3,132.50              PO-03889     4751.19   
5      INV-002537     USD 3,856.29              PO-03889     4751.19   
6      INV-002420       USD 592.43              PO-03577     1188.46   
7      INV-002415    USD 10,779.00              PO-03727     5389.21
```

Rows 4 & 5 are an example being duplicated in the PO Number & PO Subtotal columns.

I expect the output to remove the duplicate so the value is only shown once in all cases.

```
          INV           INV SUB                 PO Number PO Subtotal  \
0      INV-002504       USD 350.00              PO-03977         240   
1      INV-002507     USD 1,400.00              PO-03846      603.56   
2             NaN              NaN              PO-03847         295   
3      INV-002489       USD 891.25              PO-03861      658.31   
4      INV-002453     USD 3,132.50              PO-03889     4751.19   
5      INV-002537     USD 3,856.29                     
6      INV-002420       USD 592.43              PO-03577     1188.46   
7      INV-002415    USD 10,779.00              PO-03727     5389.21
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.2/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) to check which rows contain duplicates based on `PO Number` & `PO Subtotal`. Then conditionally replace the value by `''` with [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
m = df.duplicated(['PO Number', 'PO Subtotal'])

df['PO Number'] = np.where(m, '', df['PO Number'])
df['PO Subtotal'] = np.where(m, '', df['PO Subtotal'])
```

---

Or using `.loc` to select the correct rows and columns and replace those rows with `''`:

```
m = df.duplicated(['PO Number', 'PO Subtotal'])
df.loc[m, ['PO Number', 'PO Subtotal']] = ''
```

**Output**

```
          INV        INV SUB PO Number PO Subtotal
0  INV-002504     USD 350.00  PO-03977       240.0
1  INV-002507   USD 1,400.00  PO-03846      603.56
2         NaN            NaN  PO-03847       295.0
3  INV-002489     USD 891.25  PO-03861      658.31
4  INV-002453   USD 3,132.50  PO-03889     4751.19
5  INV-002537   USD 3,856.29                      
6  INV-002420     USD 592.43  PO-03577     1188.46
7  INV-002415  USD 10,779.00  PO-03727     5389.21
```